# Unable to delete rows from DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

Now this may be a "Noob" question. But I cant seem to do any commands that people seem to do with The DataGrid. What is the difference, and why can I only get DataGrid?

My problem is that I am trying to delete rows in the datagrid when they are pulled from a database. But, I cant figure out how because the SelectRows command does not work.

That is what i have so far. Is there anyway i can get DataGrid?

EDIT:
This is how I get information into the datagrid.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in userDataGrid.SelectedRows)
    {
        if (!row.IsNewRow)
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
} 




SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Server=----; Database=----; User id=vsd; password=----";
conn.Open();

dt = new DataTable();
sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TeacherID, ClassName, ClassID FROM CLASS", conn);
sda.Fill(dt);
userDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
conn.Close();
```

Also, If there is a better way to do this, please let me know as well. I am very new to all of this.

Comment: How do you fill your DataGrid's Items? Binding?

Comment: @Bizz I have updated the question to how I put the information in the datagrid.

Comment: It's been ages since I put aside data tables. Working with **entity framework** is so much easier. and also in order to efficiently work with wpf use **MVVM pattern**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing for deleting the button. Most answers were trying to answer to a DataGridView. But, This is not WinForms or a DataGridView. This is WPF and its just DataGrid.

This is what I did to delete the row from the grid and the database.

```
private void delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = this.aSSIGNMENTDataGrid;

        var id1 = (DataRowView)dg.SelectedItem;  //Get specific ID From                DataGrid after click on Delete Button.

        PK_ID = Convert.ToInt32(id1.Row["AssignmentID"].ToString());

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlstring);
        conn.Open();

        string sqlquery = "delete from ASSIGNMENT where AssignmentID='" + PK_ID + "' ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        filldatagrid();
    }

    private void filldatagrid()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlstring);
        conn.Open();

        string sqlquery = "select * from ASSIGNMENT";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        aSSIGNMENTDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same instance of DataTable every time when you pull rows from db.

```
DataTable mDataTable = new DataTable(); //class field

public Constructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    userDataGrid.ItemsSource = mDataTable .mDataTable;
}    

void PullData()
{
    mDataTable.Clear();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TeacherID, ClassName, ClassID FROM CLASS", conn);
        sda.Fill(mDataTable );
    }
}
```

It should solve your problem, but it's bad approach.
As Bizz adviced look at MVVM pattern & entity framework.